# How can we sum the counts of certain groups in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have the collection in which I am able to find out the counts of individual group but I want also sum some certain groups count to each other.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "loginID" : Ram.1234@gmail.com , "name" :Ram, opertion:modified }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("2"), "loginID" : Arjun34@gmail.com, "name" :  Arjun, opertion:updated }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "loginID" :Ram.1234@gmail.com , "name" : Ram,opertion:modified_ext }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "loginID" : Arjun34@gmail.com, "name" : Arjun,opertion:updated }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5"), "loginID" : Arjun34@gmail.com, "name" : Arjun,opertion:read}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6"), "loginID" : shyam78@gmail.com, "name" : Shyam,opertion:deleted }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7"), "loginID" : shyam78@gmail.com, "name" : Shyam,opertion:updated_file}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("8"), "loginID" : Arjun34@gmail.com, "name" : Arjun,opertion:read  },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("9"), "loginID" :Ram.1234@gmail.com , "name" : Ram,opertion:modified_txt },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("10"), "loginID" :Ram.1234@gmail.com , "name" : Ram,opertion:modified }
```

I am able to get the individual opertion count:-

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "operation" : "modified"
    },
    "total_document" : 2
}


{
    "_id" : {
        "operation" : "modified_txt"
    },
    "total_document" : 1
}



{
    "_id" : {
        "operation" : "modified_ext"
    },
    "total_document" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "operation" : "updated"
    },
    "total_document" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "operation" : "updated_file"
    },
    "total_document" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "operation" : "read"
    },
    "total_document" : 2
}
```

// but I want sum of some operations together.

modified=modified+modified_txt+modified_ext
similarly updated=updated+updated file

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "operation" : "modified"
    },
    "total_document" : 4
}



{
    "_id" : {
        "operation" : "updated"
    },
    "total_document" : 2
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "operation" : "read"
    },
    "total_document" : 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the operation includes a part of the name. For example: check if `"modified_txt"` includes the word `"modified"`.

Here is a basic example.

```js
const actions = [
  "modified",
  "updated",
  "modified_ext",
  "updated",
  "read",
  "deleted",
  "updated_file",
  "read",
  "modified_txt",
  "deleted",
  "modified",
  "deleted_txt"
];

const valuesToGroup = [
  "modified",
  "read",
  "updated",
];

const count = actions.reduce((all, action) => {
  // Operations to group
  for(const operation of valuesToGroup) {
    if(action.includes(operation)) {
      all[operation] = all[operation] ? all[operation] + 1 : 1;
      
      return all;
    };
  }
  
  // Everything else
  all[action] = all[action] ? all[action] + 1 : 1;

  return all;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Hi I want to write mongodb query which will sum certain opertion. Operation name may be differ.

Comment: @Sharadskumar I updated to snippet to group items based on a string you specify, everything else will just be counted normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {//string operations to get the common groups
      "total_document": 1,
      "groupWord": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$split": [
              "$_id.operation",
              "_"
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {//General sum operation
      "_id": "$groupWord",
      "total": {
        $sum: "$total_document"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F6h1CnkxL2f)